# how to post data to remote server using ajax,js,html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send data from html page to server
Below is my json example.
On my html page question label and for this four option like A,B,C,D and option are in radio button form after click on send button i want to send data like below json format to remote server.

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "question": "What is the answer. 2+3=?",
            "answer": "B"
        },
        {
            "question": "What is the answer. 3-1=?",
            "answer": "A"
        },
        {
            "question": "What is the answer. 3*2=?",
            "answer": "B"
        },
        {
            "question": "What is the answer. 3/3=?",
            "answer": "A"
        },
        {
            "question": "What is the answer. 6%3=?",
            "answer": "D"
        },
        {
            "question": "What is the answer. 6+3=?",
            "answer": "NA"
        },
        {
            "question": "What is the answer. 2+3+3=?",
            "answer": "A"
        },
        {
            "question": "What is the answer. 3+3-2=?",
            "answer": "NA"
        },
        {
            "question": "What is the answer. 2*3*3=?",
            "answer": "D"
        },
        {
            "question": "What is the answer. 2*3+3=?",
            "answer": "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax to send the data to remote server like this (let your json be saved in a variable - `var json_data` in JS):

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : "url_for_remote_server",
    data : json_data,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
    },
    error : function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    },
    done : function(e) {
        console.log("DONE");
    }
});
```

> See more about [jQuery Ajax Requests](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**UPDATE**

See the below code bock, which shows how to get data from HTML and form a json array through it:

```js
$(function() {

 $('.submitBtn').on('click', function(e) {
   var jsonArr = [];
    
    $('.ques_block').each(function(i) {
     var text = $(this).find('label').text();
      var option = $(this).find("select").val();
      jsonArr.push({
       'text': text,
        'option': option
      });
    });
    
    console.log(jsonArr);
  });

});
```

```css
.options {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.ques_block{
      margin-top: 30px;
}

.submitBtn {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-block">

  <div class="ques_block">
    <label>Q1. Select any 1 option from below?</label>
    <div class='options'>
      <select>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="ques_block">
    <label>Q1. Select any 1 option from below?</label>
    <div class='options'>
      <select>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <button class="submitBtn">
    Submit
  </button>

</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to send json like mention above format.The html page contain label and radio button. Label for question and radio button for option.

Comment: @PranitBhor - See my updated section above. I've added a code block to make it more understandable!

Comment: @PranitBhor - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!